# How to use Yii components in the web-app?

Tags: php, yii, components

I've written test component which located in `/protected/components/document.php`:

```
class Document extends CComponent{
    private $_width;
    public __construct($width){
        this->_width=$width;
    }
    public function getWidth(){
        return $this->_width;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use this component in one of my controller's action as the following:

```
$docum=new Document('150');
echo $docum->width;
```

But the following exception is raised:

```
include(Document.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should rename your file from `document.php` to `Document.php`. Secondly if you want to create its instance via `new` you should not extend it from `CComponent` class.

To use component without creating it via `new` you should

1. Extend your class from CApplicationComponent.
2. Configure it in config.php at components section:

   'document' => array(
       'class' => 'Document',
       // other properties
   ),
3. Use it as Yii::app()->document->method();

Also if you extend your class from CApplicationComponent you should not define __construct method, instead all initialization should occur at overridden `init()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand you. How can I using components in my app without new? I've read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component but there is no info about embedding component class into the application.

Answer (score -1):

basicly its missing to import the file:

```
Yii::import('application.components.Document');
```